# How to inject OrderEntry context inside outlet CartOutlets.ITEM_DETAILS in Spartacus

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

A question found in a different channel:

> Is there any way to access orderEntry when using
>
> ```html
> <ng-template [cxOutlet]="CartOutlets.ITEM_DETAILS"> </ng-template>
> ```
>
> placeholder from cart-item component? It seems that when there is no `[cxOutletContext]="{ entry: item }"` it is not possible, and we have to overwrite / copy entire cart component (cart-details, cart-item-list, cart-item) to display some additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Spartacus 4.3.x:**

You should be able to inject the special token [`CartItemContext`](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/4.3.x/projects/storefrontlib/cms-components/cart/cart-shared/cart-item/model/cart-item-context.model.ts#L11-L23) like in [this example component](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/4.3.x/feature-libs/product-configurator/common/components/configurator-issues-notification/configurator-issues-notification.component.ts#L17).

And you might be interested especially in reading the `CartItemContext.item$`, which has type `Observable<OrderEntry>`.

Note: As of version 4.3.x, he `CartItemContext` token is provided only inside the default component [CartItemComponent](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/4.3.x/projects/storefrontlib/cms-components/cart/cart-shared/cart-item/cart-item.component.ts#L18-L22).